# Change Magento product status in different store views

Tags: magento, store, product

I have a Magento Multi-Store installation.

I have a product that must be enabled in shopA and disabled in shopB

If i select the tab "Websites" there is an alert 
"Items that you don't want to show in the catalog or search results should have status 'Disabled' in the desired store." so probably it is possible?

The default value status of the product is "enabled"

Then i select the store view of shopB and disabled the product status.
Now the status of the product in shopA is also disabled.

Is it possible to set the product status in shopA to enabled en in shopB to disabled?

The manual said:
"The Product Status has a Website scope, meaning that you can hide or show a product per Website, affecting all store views for that Website. "

source: 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/catalog/how_the_store_view_affects_categories_and_products

The question is: Is it possible to change the product status per store view without affecting other store views

Answer (score 1):

You have got your cache cleared, indexes rebuilt and so forth?

Otherwise you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are saying that your store is only a multi-store, so I don't think you will see a "`Websites`" tab, in that product's details page. So, you have only one way to make this product enabled in "`Shop A`" & disabled in "`Shop B`".

In the product's details page, Magento loads the "`General`" tab, in which you will see the "`Status`" field.
Now, in the left side, above the "`General`" tab, you will find a dropdown field for "`Choose Store View:`". If you click on the dropdown, you will see a list of all your store views available under each Website & Store.

Now select the "`Shop B`" in that dropdown. Magento will ask you that it will erase any unsaved data from the current view in Admin, if you have changed any data, without saving it. Without worrying on this part, click the "`OK`" button of that dialog box, & Magento will then load the "`Shop B`" store view of that same product.

Here beside the "`Status`" field, you will find a checkbox. Make sure that it's not checked. Now change the value of the "`Status`" dropdown to "`Disabled`" & save the changes.

Now go to the front-end of your "`Shop B`" store view & you shouldn't be able to see this product again. But it will also be active in the "`Shop A`" store view.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That is exactly the way i did it. But when i go to shop B and unckecked the checkbox and change the value in the dropdown box to "disabled". it will also change the value in shop A to "disabled"

Comment: I also checked now myself that if you want to take this effect to take place with respect to store views, then it will not be possible, and this change takes place in a website-wise fashion. This is because the "`Status`" attribute is maintained with "`Website`" scope, instead of "`Store View`" scope. This is what Magento has defined it to be.

Comment: Instead if you try to maintain this new shop in a new website (but with all the same configurations like that of the present website), then your requirement will be just fine, without any issues.

Comment: I'm very sorry, but I don't want anybody to change the default Magento's settings, because that may hamper creating / maintaining products in the long run.

Comment: It's not a standard option to change the product status without affecting the other store views but you can change the visibillity in a store view. In shop A is the visibillity "catalogus" and in shop B is the visibillity "not visible indvidually". This worked for me. The product is now not visible in Shop B

Comment: @Bob - Thanks very much, for letting me know about it also. Many Cheers!

Comment: See my answer on how to change this attribute's scope. Pretty simple :)

Answer (score 0):

So many years withouth proper answer.
I have no idea why but magento doesn't offer the posibility to change status scope to store view. Found a workaround.
Find the attribute in catalog_eav_attribute and change it's is_global value to 0 - this means store view and works perfectly as it should in the first place :)

Now it's filling only selected view value in catalog_product_entity_int table instead of all views in the website scope.

Answer (score -1):

the "Status" attribute in the product page detail is valid for Website and not for store!

bye